# Array filter method is not returning trimmed values

Tags: javascript

```
let un_trimmed = ["push", " pop", "shift", "  "];
filtered = un_trimmed.filter(function (el) {
  return el.trim();
});
```

// output :
`["push", " pop", "shift"]`  (notice the un-trimmed value of " pop")
// Expected output :
`["push", "pop", "shift"]`  (notice the trimmed value of "pop")

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) *only* uses the return value to decide whether to include the input value in the output or not; it does not modify the input value. To do that, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) then `filter`:

```js
let un_trimmed = ["push", " pop", "shift", "  "];
filtered = un_trimmed.map(function (el) {
  return el.trim();
}).filter(Boolean);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 3):

What `.filter` does is it returns a new array containing elements from the old array that pass the callback's test *without modification*. You need a `.map` followed by a `.filter`, since you both need to *change* certain values and *remove entirely* certain values:

```js
let un_trimmed = ["push", " pop", "shift", "  "];
const filtered = un_trimmed
  .map(str => str.trim())
  .filter(str => str);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `.filter(Boolean)` and `.filter(str=>str)` ?

Comment: Nope, they're identical.